# Колыхни - дотронься?

Tags: лексика

Хочу повесить на "ветерок" слова типа: колыхни (ДОТРОНЬСЯ),ЕСЛИ ТЫ СЧАСТЛИВ. И "ветерок" должен будет зазвучать... Но не найти подходящего глагола: колыхни - неблагозвучно, дотронься - не отражает смысл... Может, кому-то в голову придет более удачный глагол?

Comment: Что такое "ветерок"?

Напишите просто, как у Кассиля:
"Прозба не дербанить в парадное, а сувать пальцем в пупку для звонка".

Comment: Спасибо. Оценила Ваш совет)))
"Ветерок" - это такой необычный колокольчик - шесть больших металлических трубочек висят по кругу на веревочках, прикрепленных к деревянному основанию. Посередине деревянный язычок. Вешают его обычно не у входа в квартиру, а у входа в комнату или ,как у меня, в прихожую. Этот ветерок-колокольчик издает легкую, переливчатую мелодию, когда до него дотрагиваешься...

Comment: А, понял... Не знал, что это "ветерок".
Может, тогда - "прикоснись"?
И чем вам "всколыхни" не нравится?

Comment: "Прикоснись" - не создает движения и музыки этого "ветерка". Да, "всколыхни" - лучше по смыслу, но какое-то неблагозвучное, подозреваю, что и не всем понятное...

Answer (score 2):

1.Коснись - и звук серебряный польётся
2.Лёгкое касание - и серебро звучания
3.От лёгкого касания - счастья ожидание

Comment: Или:От лёгкого касания-счастье ожидания

Answer (score 1):

Мне бы больше понравился вариант, если б на китайских колокольчиках было написано, - *Прозвени, если ты счастлив*.

Другие варианты глагола: Раззвени, позвони, отзвенись, звени, зазвени, прикоснись, растрепи, потряси, погладь, раскачай, звякни, сыграй, пробренчи, прозвякай и пр.

Answer (score 1):

Если ты счастлив, он отзовётся.